# Code Coverage Using JaCoCo

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco

I'M trying to get the Code Coverage using JaCoCo-javaagent passing VM argument

> > **-javaagent:/test/jacoco/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/test/jacoco/jacoco.exec,includes=com.*,append=true**

I'M able to get some value in jacoco.exec file but not able to get coverage report.How can i convert jacoco.exec to coverage report **OR** am i missing something in VM Argument.

Condition is like that i have only jar and war and using jBoss server to run application.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate JaCoCo report by using `org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report` maven goal. For example:

*pom.xml*

```
...
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>jacoco-report</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                <goal>report</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

After `mvn -Pjacoco-report clean install` jacoco maven plugin generate the report in `target/site/jacoco` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Run [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org), which includes excellent JaCoCo reporting. No need to parse the binary output from JaCoCo yourself.

Links to instructions for running it with various tools, including the command line are [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/).

You'll need to run a sonar server. You can download it [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/). On a Mac, you can do

1. `brew install sonar`
2. `sonar console`

The commands for Maven, for example, are

1. `mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`
2. `mvn sonar:sonar`